# Make one epub file out of a list of epub files (One per character)

Tags: python, epub

I have a list of epub files one per chapter which I want to merge into one ebook.

The epubs were generated by google docs export to epub if it matters.

Example for chapter files can be seen here: https://github.com/NoamDev/hpmor-heb/tree/master/dist/hpmor/chapters/epub (It's hebrew language).

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure writing code to merge the epubs is easier than just merging the google docs you generated them from, and exporting a single file?

Comment: Might be of interest: https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/1067

Comment: @Blckknght I couldn't find an easy way of merging Google Docs using the API.